# <a> tags not working in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I put a calendar of events put together using angular and jquery. A styled button saying +My Schedule adds the data to localStorage which is then pulled in to another page for user's reference. The localStorage function worked fine until it was brought into the Angular template. Clicking the link now cause the page to jump up and there is nothing recorded in the console or localStorage.
A working example of what I am trying to do is at the following url, this page was all hard coded and I am trying to implement the same thing in an Angular template: http://events.latimes.com/festivalofbooks/the-festival/schedule/
Any help would be appreciated.
Here is a fiddle: http://plnkr.co/edit/gaKFWTsACxwCg0i4JCiw?p=preview
Here is the shortened template as I had to paste code here:

```
 <table class="target-stage stage-only" border="0" cellspacing="0" 
 cellpadding="0" style="border:none;" > 
      <tr>
        <td width="190" valign="top" class="ev-time">{{item.time}}</td>
        <td valign="top" class="ev-desc">
        <p class="ev-date">{{item.day}}, {{item.date}}, 2015</p>
        <strong>{{item.first_name}} {{item.last_name}},</strong> Author of 
 <em>" {{item.work_title}}"</em><br />
        {{item.stage}}
        <span class="info-btn"><p class="selctor" rel={{item.rel}}><span     
 class="addSchd"><a href="#"><b>+ MY SCHEDULE</b></a></span>
        </td>
      </tr>
 </table>
```

Comment: Shouldn't you have a click action on the href that interacts with the localStorage? At this point, I think your code is doing exactly what it is programmed to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm seeing a few problems here.
First of all, your html is broken. The p-tag is never closed.

```
<span class="info-btn"><p class="selctor" rel={{item.rel}}><span class="addSchd"><a href="#"><b>+ MY SCHEDULE</b></a></span>
```

Second, as far as I've seen from taking a quick look you are dynamically adding content. You can't use (selector).click() on dynamic content, because the selector won't exist at the point that code is called. Instead use on(), which will be applied to dynamically generated content as well like this:

```
$(document).on("click", ".button", function() {
    // do this when class with .button is clicked
});
```

Comment: You're welcome. You can mark your question as answered so it's easier for others who have the same issue.